# A: visited пройденные ссылки

Tags: css

Мне нужно чтобы пройденные ссылки a.refer:visited{color:#817000;} при обновлении страницы принимали свой первоначальный цвет a.refer:link{color:#AEFFFF;}

Comment: а какой первоначальный цвет ?

Comment: Попробуйте более подробно расписать задачу.

Comment: В первом приближении если есть клик по ссылке - открывается другая страница. Значит на исходной странице уже не важно какого цвета посещенная ссылка - эта страница уже не отображается. Допустим ссылка ведет на якорь на той же странице, но страница все равно будет загружена заново и нужно будет отобразить все ссылки первоначальным цветом. Короче говоря чушь вы хотите.

Answer (score 2):

a.refer:visited{
color: #AEFFFF;
}